# Unresolved external symbol Sphlib - sph_blake512_init?

Tags: c, sphlib

I'm having trouble with what I've thought would be a trivially easy task.
There is a Sphlib (Saphir 2.0) library containing hash functions.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Scenario:
    I want to import Blake512 hash function into my project so I do the following:

```
1) import sph_types.h into my project
2)import sph_blake.h
3) import blake.c
```

everything compiles but if include a sample invocation of a function I get an error during linking stage.

```
  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl sph_blake512_init(void *)"
```

I've been fighting with this for quite some time.
I think it has got to do with the included macros but I do not know how to force VS to evaluate them properly. some macro-magic is being done in the sph_types.h that's what I know.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. I was trying to reference a C function from C++.
I  surrounded function's definition with

```
        #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif
    FUNCTION DECLARATION
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif`
```

and it's fine.